# Sort a List<String[]> numerically

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sorting, numerical

I have a `List<string[]>`. I add to it with `list.Add(new string[] {a, b, c, d})`, where `d` is a string of numbers.

I want to sort the list numerically by the number in the fourth element of the array. So far I've only found this:

```
list.Sort((s, t) => String.Compare(s[3], t[3]));
```

but this sorts alphabetically, so 10 gets in front of 2 etc.

Is there an equally simple way to sort it numerically?

Comment: How are you adding data to this list? Show some real lines of code.

Comment: Also, show the definition of `list`.

Comment: List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>(); I take the a b c d variables from Console.ReadLine() add them to the list with the list.Add(new string[] {a,b,c,d})

Comment: This seems like a custom class would be a better option than `string[]`. I think you should consider changing that.

Comment: @svick a custom class does sound better. It sounds like  the inner array is actually a data structure of some sort. Arrays within arrays are generally a recipe for disaster, especially for anyone maintaining this code later who don't understand the index mappings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use linq, you can do:

```
list = list.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x[3])).ToList();
```

This will create a new list though and probably won't be as efficient as sorting the list directly.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
list.Sort((s, t) => int.Compare(int.Parse(s[3]), int.Parse(t[3])));
```

or (if the list is all numbers, and you want the result as numbers):

```
list = list.Select(n => n.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray()).OrderBy(x => x[3]).ToList();
```

(excuse formatting, on mobile)

Answer (score 0):

```
list.Sort((s, t) => System.Collections.Comparer.Default.Compare(Int32.Parse(s[3]), Int32.Parse(t[3])));
```

My suggestion is that you should really implement your own class with public members a,b,c and d. You should then implement `IComparable<T>` and write your simple comparison logic in `CompareTo()` method.

Comment: This one also has the disadvantage of not sorting numerically. It will certainly not use anything related to `Int32`.

Comment: @svick: How do you guess that?

Comment: Why would you expect the default comparer for strings to sort numerically? It doesn't do that.

Comment: @svick: ah, my mistake. I thought the 4th element was an `int`. Thanks for pointing out. I have corrected my code.

Comment: Details are still off. You say that it won't crash on a non-numeric entry, it will.

Comment: @svick: Not my day then. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution (I have not seen here) is to implement a delegate as a sorter

```
 // Split the string into individual number strings
 List<String> items  = wrongOrderBase.Split(DELIMITER).ToList<String>();
 items.Sort(delegate(String strA, String strB)
            {
                int intA = int.Parse(strA);
                int intB = int.Parse(strB);
                return intA.CompareTo(intB);
            });
  // Re-join back into one string
  String sortedListString = String.Join(DELIMITER.ToString(), items);
```

This way if you want to do any special case stuff you can implement it in the delegate.